# Dictionary or Encyclopedia of Fantasy or Fairy Tales from the 1960s

Tags: story-identification, books, fairy-tales

I remember seeing an illustrated dictionary or encyclopedia of fantasy stories or fairy tales in a book store during the period of 1961-1968.

I remember a few details about some of the entries.

The entry on dragons began: "Dragons drag." And it accused dragons of basically doing nothing despite their great powers.

The entry on dukes mentioned that dukes were almost kings, so close to being kings that the difference made them bitter and they were always plotting against kings.

It was mentioned that wizards usually lived in towers.

And I remember an illustration, a chart with specimens of the various fantasy or fairy tales species side by side for identification.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Byfield's Book of Weird* (1967) by Barbara Ninde Byfield, also called *The Glass Harmonica: A Lexicon of the Fantastical*<sup>[1](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1AHXW7VGTXNVN?ref=pf_vv_at_pdctrvw_srp)</sup>.

A quote from the book:

> Dragons drag: they are lazy, sluggish and prefer to live on their reputations.
>   
> <sub>[Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/rec.arts.books.childrens/ey6KL8MhUos)</sub>

A wizard's tower is shown on the right side of [this scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM3Xg.jpg).

---

Found with the Google search `"dragons drag" encyclopedia`, i.e. searching for the exact phrase "dragons drag" and the word "encyclopedia" or synonyms/other spellings.

The alternate name was referenced [here](https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/552706/), then, to verify it was the same with another source, I found [an Amazon page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1135189676) for it under that name and then got a link to the review that I saw on the page by looking at the user's profile and scrolling down a lot.

Comment: *Book of Weird* (previously published as *The Glass Harmonica*) is not the same book as *The Eating in Bed Cook Book*.  I think the correct answer is *Book of Weird*: http://intothedarkdimension.blogspot.com/2012/09/the-book-of-weird.html

Comment: [Archived link for if the linked site is ever taken down](https://archive.is/ror9S)

Comment: Somewhat similar sources include:

*The encyclopedia of Fantasy* (1997) 


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Encyclopedia_of_Fantasy[2]

*The Tough Guide to Fantasyland*, Diane Wynter Jones (1996, 2006) 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tough_Guide_to_Fantasyland[3] 
  [2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Encyclopedia_of_Fantasy
  [3]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tough_Guide_to_Fantasyland
  [

Comment: @M.A.Golding I am searching for a similar book which I am SURE I read before 1993 or so based on my location - also an encyclopedia of fantasy or fantasy worlds, which I'm trying to track down. Any others on your list? Thanks